# How to use Guice's Injector?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I'm in process of learning Guice and I don't clearly understand how to use `Injector` instance. It's better to create `Injector` instance once on application bootstrap, and make it public singleton?

And is it true that we always must use `Injector#getInstance(SomeClass.class)` to get classes where we putted Guice's `@Inject` annotations?

Comment: It's better to not use `Injector.getInstance()` at all.

Comment: @millimoose but what is other ways to retrieve classes managed by Guice?

Comment: Fields annotated with `@Inject` should have the right classes available "automagically". (Assuming you have Guice manage the classes that need injecting too.) The idea is that you have the container manage both your dependencies, **and** the classes that use them, and only fetch one "main" class from the injector manually to start your app. You should also consider [rereading the tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted), this is Dependency Injection 101.

Comment: Yes, I read it before asking question, but class that has fields annotated with `@Inject` must be retrieved using `Injector#getInstance(MyClass.class)`. So what if I have multiple classes with fields annotated with `@Inject`? I need to initiate every class using `Injector#getInstance(ClassName.class)`.

Comment: Ah. Not necessarily. Only if you need to call a method on one from a class that's not managed by Guice. Alternately you can instead do `Injector.injectMembers(this)` and populate all fields annotated with `@Inject` from the `Injector` even on an unmanaged object.

Comment: Yes, I call guice-managed class from class which don't know anything about guice (so it don't work). I tested `Injector.injectMembers(this)`. As I understand I need to call this method in every class which has `@Inject` annotations?

Comment: No, only for objects that aren't Guice-managed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not pass the injector around as a global singleton. Have you looked at: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted? Note that `RealBillingService` does not use the injector to get instances of `CreditCardProcessor` and `TransactionLog`. Instead Guice handles all this for you when creating the instance.

If you're in a situation where you need Guice to create many objects of the same type consider using a [Provider](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) and injecting that provider.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But what if I have multiple services like `RealBillingService`, and each of them have `@Inject` annotations for injecting `CreditCardProcessor` and `TransactionLog` objects. So I need use `Injector#getInstance` for every service like `RealBillingService`. But I want to create this services in different places, so I have 2 variants: create `Injector` object in every place and use `Injector#getInstance` for retrieving neccessary service _or_ to create `Injector` instance once make it accessible (global singleton) to all places where I need it.

Comment: Or have a third object that has the instances of your two services (both annotated with `@Inject`). Then you would use the `Injector` to get the single instance of this third object.

Comment: In practice you rarely see the `injector`. If you're using `Jersey` with `Guice`, for instance, you configure your Modules and then the framework handles the rest.

Comment: i.e. Jersey have support for Guice out of the box? It like: Jersey is Guice-managed component, so we don't need to explicitly use `Injector` instance?

Comment: Or you mean Jersey in context of JEE container? I.e. CDI (Guice) can be used only in container-manager components, like EJB, JAX-RS (Jersey), JAX-WS etc without explicitly using `Injector#getInstance`?

Comment: Not out of the box. You need to add a dependency to `jersey-guice`. See an example here: http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-guice-ified-jersey-in-embedded.html and note that the Injector is not used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24396/discussion-between-condit-and-mytitle)