# Guice @Inject doesn't work

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, guice, entitylisteners

I have Guice for DI.
I can inject my repository in the controller (constructor injection):

```
@ImplementedBy(JPAMyEntityRepository.class)
public interface MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository<MyEntity> {

}

@Singleton
public class JPAMyEntityRepository implements MyEntityRepository {
.....
}

public class MyEntityController extends BaseController {

    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Inject
    public MyEntityController(MyEntityRepository myEntityRepo) {
        this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepo; //OK, repo is not null
    }
}
```

But I can't inject the same repository in my entity listener using constructor, I have an exception (there aren't default constructor):

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public abstract class MyEntity extends OwnedEntity implements Comparable<MyEntity> {
    ....
}

public class MyEntityListener {

    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    @Inject
    public MyEntityListener(MyEntityRepository myEntityRepo){
        this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepo; 
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
....
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to create instance of models.listeners.MyEntityListener as a JPA callback listener
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: models.listeners.MyEntityListener.<init>()
```

And when i try to inject my repo in such approach:

```
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Inject
    private MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository; // null
}
```

I have a null.

Build.sbt file:

```
import MetamodelGenerator.generateMetamodels

name := """my-app"""

version := "1.2.4-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(sourceGenerators in Compile += generateMetamodels(Seq("models")).taskValue)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.projectDependencies
```

application.conf file:

```
# JDBC
db {
    default {
        driver = org.postgresql.Driver
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-app"
        schema = myapp
        username = "user"
        password = "user"
        jndiName = DefaultDS
        logSql = false

        hikaricp {
            connectionTestQuery = SELECT 1
            minimumIdle = 20
            maximumPoolSize = 40
        }
    }
}
# Point JPA at our database configuration
jpa.default = defaultPersistenceUnit

# Job queue sized to HikariCP connection pool
database.dispatcher {
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
    throughput = 1
    thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 40
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the code of your Guice configuration?

Comment: I have no special configs for this situation

Comment: do you know this documentation https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA?

Comment: Yes, and I have persistence.xml config, but i don't understand why I can inject in one class, but can't inject in another class

Comment: I think your are facing a smilar problem like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840413/using-guice-injection-in-custom-authenticator-on-google-cloud-endpoints.

Comment: Injecting isn't "wonderfull machine". Injecting enine (Guiice) mus have possibility to inject. First example when injecting DON"T work are object created is simplest way by 'new'

Comment: Yes, Entity listeners are created by JPA Provider (not by Guice), so injecting doesn't work in this case. I understood.